# how are characterized categories that are determined by they graph up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, category-theory

I know that thin categories have this property, but i also know that they are not the only ones. What are other kinds of categories that have this property? Is there any characterization of that fact?(i.e. exactly what categories have this property)

Edit:
For example this graph determines a category univocally(up to isomorphism), though is not thin.(Obviously i assume distinct vertices are distinct objects and distinct arrows are distinct morphisms.
)[image]

Comment: Do you mean graphs with exactly one category structure? Perhaps something like 'parallel arrows $A\to B$ should be separated, i.e. no $C\to A$ or $B\to C$ arrows exist (other than the identity).

Comment: That's exactly what i meant. Those categories are surely determined by their graph, however there are others that do not satesfy that property, but are determined by their graph.(i.e. is not a characterization)

Comment: Can you tell us an example?

Comment: I have added an example of a graph without your properties, but that determines a category univocally.(up to isomorphisms).

Comment: Ok, next try: 'In every connected component there's at most one pair of objects with multiple parallel arrows in between'.

Comment: I think adding a parallel arrow next to the vertical one in my previous example makes a counterexample. I also think we have to make restrictions on compositions of morphisms, for example if you add a diagonal arrow to my example diagram you can have two different non isomorphic categories.